# OSSEC_HIDS Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: docker, kubernetes, ossec

**Which would be the best HIDS (HostBase Intrusion Detection System) to deploy on Kubernetes Google Cloud Platform**

I want to build docker image on debian:stable-slim

So I have been testing the ossec-docker and wazuh-docker 
here are repos respectively:

1. OSSEC: https://github.com/Atomicorp/ossec-docker
2. WAZUH: https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-docker

The wazuh-api=3.7.2-1 is broken as I am unable to get it install on debian:stable-slim

with nodejs: 6.10.0 or higher as it needs nodejs version >=4.6.0
but api is unable to install

I would need to know if anyone can suggest HostBase Intrusion Detection system which I can configure and deploy on docker/ Kubernetes If you have any github repo link would really appreciate the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wazuh has a [repository for Kubernetes](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kubernetes). Right now, it is focused on AWS, but I think you just need to change the volumes configuration (it is implemented for AWS EBS) and it should work in GCP.